# Laravel real-time notification not showing into console from Pusher

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-notification

I'm implementing Real-Time Notification in my Laravel project. I'm very close to achieve my goal. What I have done so far is I have saved the notifications into database and now wanted to render the same notification to user using Pusher.

I got response into Pusher but the issue is I' m not able to receive the notification in my console and under the console of another user to make it work like real time.

Currently, notifications are sending to Pusher, saving into database but notification is not showing into console.

App.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

//getting the ID's of all logged-in users
let userId = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="user-id"]').content;

Echo.private('App.Models.User.' + userId)
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification.type);
    });

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');

window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Laravel.csrfToken);

    next();
});

import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key:'8c1d04bb8d1782b874b1',
    cluster: 'ap2',
    encrypted: false
});
```

DatabaseNotification.php

```
<?php

class DatabaseNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    private  $subscription;
    public function __construct($letter)
    {
        $this->subscription = $letter;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database','broadcast'];
    }

    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'letter' => $this->subscription,
        ];

    }

    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'letter' => $this->subscription,
            'count' => $notifiable->unreadNotifications->count(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Response in Pusher
[image]

Comment: Could you please attach logs from your console. If you are able to send message to pusher than issue is somewhere on consumer side.

Comment: @OlegAndreyev My console is neat and clean. It's showing nothing but I can see the notification on my bell icon.

Comment: Well it looks like you are pushing `App.User.2` but listening to `App.Models.User.' + userId`

Comment: @OlegAndreyev It was good catch and I modified the line of code also but still no response. Btw, I neither created any Event file nor I did anything with channel.php. Do you think I need to touch them as well ?

Comment: have you checked that  App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class is uncommented from config/app.php file?

Comment: @imranqasim Yes !. Super stuck to see what's going wrong :(